# Shinyapps.io connects to account but it does not deploy

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, web-deployment, shinyapps

I have already deployed about 8 web apps in [www.shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io) with my personal free account, everyone of them from my personal computer. However, I am right now trying to deploy a shiny app the same way I did the whole past times, but this time with my work computer and up to now I failed. I tried by restarting this pc and unconnecting Forticlient VPN so I work from home; that either did not work. The problem is this: after connecting RStudio to my shinyapps.io account (what you do when you introduce token), I push "publish", then normaly it should triggers a new tab or window in my explorer (mine is MS Edge), and this is not happening, it just appears to accept the order and do not show any error neither shows new tabs nor windows. It just simply does not work, the app never loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the app in my personal computer and it worked. It must be a security issue which does not let me connect appropriately to shinyapps.io servers.